# How to control which line gets what marker in a seaborn multi-line plot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I am not able to control which data category gets what marker in a multiple line plots in seaborn. To demonstrate what I am trying to do here is a contrived example -

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set(style="ticks")
sns.set_context("paper", rc={"font.size":8,"axes.titlesize":20,"axes.labelsize":15})
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4], 'B': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c'], 'C': [1,1,3,4,1,1,3,3,1,1,2,3]})

sns.lineplot(x='A', y='C', hue='B', hue_order=['c', 'b', 'a'], markers=[{'c': 'X', 'b': 's', 'a': 'o'}], palette={'a': 'Orange', 'b': 'Green', 'c': 'Red'}, dashes=False, data=df, markers=True, ax=ax)

plt.title('A Plot')
ax.set(xlabel='Time', ylabel='#')
ax.legend(title='Legend', loc='upper left', labels=['A', 'B', 'C'])
ax.set(xticks=df['A'].values)
plt.gca().set_position([0, 0, 1, 1])
plt.show()
```

But the image renders without any markers -
[image: no markers in plot]

When I do `style='B'` I get the following error -

```
ValueError: These `style` levels are missing markers: {'b', 'c'}
```

I experimented with `style_order=['a', 'b', 'c']` but I get the same plot as above.

**How do I actually get the markers with the correct plot line?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide both `hue="B"` and `style="B"`, and then provide a dictionary to `markers={...}` (you actually passed a list containing a dictionary in your code).

```
sns.lineplot(x='A', y='C', hue='B', style='B', data=df, hue_order=['c', 'b', 'a'], markers={'c': 'X', 'b': 's', 'a': 'o'}, dashes=False, palette={'a': 'Orange', 'b': 'Green', 'c': 'Red'})
```

[image]

Comment: Would you happen to know how to reduce the white-space/white-padding around the markers in the image. Because when I save the plot as a large image then its quite significant. Please do let me know or guide to a reference.

Comment: Ah no worries, I got it - `kwargs = {'markeredgewidth': 0.25}`